# Time difference in pandas (from string format to datetime)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column

```
Time
2:00
00:13
1:00
00:24
```

in object format (strings). This time refers to hours and minutes ago from a time that I need to use as a start: `8:00` (it might change; in this example is 8:00).

Since the times in the column `Time` are referring to `hours/minutes` ago, what I would like to expect should be

```
Time
6:00
07:47
7:00
07:36
```

calculated as time difference (e.g. `8:00 - 2:00`). 
However, I am having difficulties in doing this calculation and transform the result in a datetime (keeping only hours and minutes).
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why `00:36`  on the last row and not `07:36`?

Comment: Added a question related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205855/converting-string-value-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using `pd.to_datetime`.

```
ref = pd.to_datetime('08:00') #here define the hour of reference
s = ref-pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
print (s)
0   06:00:00
1   07:47:00
2   07:00:00
3   07:36:00
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This return a series, that can be change to a dataframe with `s.to_frame()` for example

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T . In case there are also other columns, what should I change?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro not much, just assign the column back in the dataframe if it is what you want, a bit like in @Quang answer with `df['start'] = ref-pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` otherwise because the column Time is selected at the second row, even if you have more column it does not change

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting this error: `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:` and the text of another column using your code or `ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation:` using Quang Hoang

Comment: @LucaDiMauro maybe you have bad format of data, so use `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], errors='coerce')` but then you'll got some nan to see where the error are from

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Time` columns contains only `Hour:Minute` I suggest using `timedelta` instead of `datetime`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time+':00')
df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_timedelta('8:00:00') - df['Time']
```

Output:

```
      Time Start_Time
0 02:00:00   06:00:00
1 00:13:00   07:47:00
2 01:00:00   07:00:00
3 00:24:00   07:36:00
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang Hoang. I would like to ask you what I should change in case I have other columns in my dataframe.

Comment: @Ben.Tjust a personal oppinion, it makes more sense to me as it does not depend on the date you run the code. Plus, this aligns with OP's *This time refers to hours and minutes **ago** from a time*

Comment: @LucaDiMauro This does not have anything to do with other columns.

Comment: I asked because I am getting this error: `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:` and the text of another column using Ben T. code or `ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation:` using yours

Comment: Your `Time` columns contains more that just `HH:MM` format. You can try `pd.to_timedelta(df.Time+':00', errors='coerce')`. But I suggest you re-examine your data.